# Java: String.replace(regex, string) to remove content from XML

Tags: java, xml, regex

Lets say I have an XML in the form of a string. I wish to remove the content between two tags within the XML String, say . I have tried:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceFirst("\\<tagName>.*?\\<//tagName>",
                                                              "Content Removed");
```

but it does not work. Any pointers as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have anything other than the most simple, non-nested xml a regex isn't going to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, apart from the obvious answer ([don't parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)), maybe we can fix this:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceFirst("(?s)<tagName[^>]*>.*?</tagName>",
                                          "Content Removed");
```

Explanation:

```
(?s)             # turn single-line mode on (otherwise '.' won't match '\n')
<tagName         # remove unnecessary (and perhaps erroneous) escapes
[^>]*            # allow optional attributes
>.*?</tagName>
```

Are you sure your matching the tag case correctly? Perhaps you also want to add the [`i`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag to the pattern: `(?si)`

Comment: In the end, simply using string.replaceFirst("<tagName>.*</tagName>", 
"Content Removed"); worked fine, I don't know why I was making it so complicated. Thanks for explaining the regex attributes in Java though, pretty helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem lies here:

`<//tagName>`

Try changing it to

`<\/tagName>`

Comment: In Java, `</tagName>`will do nicely without any escapes.

Comment: @Pable yes, but that doesn't use a Java Regex engine, it's flex / flash

Comment: @Pable no, it works, it's just not necessary:  "A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct." ( [source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs) )

Comment: All right so no harm done then. Thanks for the info (and BTW it's Pablo not Pable :) )

Comment: @Pablo Grrr, the same typo twice. I knew it was Pablo all along, but somehow my fingers didn't agree. Sorry!!!

Answer (score 0):

XML is a grammar; regular expressions are not the best tools to work with grammars.

My advice would be working with a real parser to work with the DOM instead of doing matches

For example, if you have:

```
<xml>
 <items>
  <myItem>
     <tagtoRemove>something1</tagToRemove>
  </myItem>
  <myItem>
     <tagtoRemove>something2</tagToRemove>
  </myItem>
 </items>
```

A regex could try to match it (due to the greedy mechanism)

```
<xml>
 <items>
  <myItem>
     matchString
  </myItem>
 </items>
```

Also, some uses that some DTDs may allow (such as `<tagToRemove/>` or `<tagToRemove attr="value">`) make catching tags with regex more difficult.

Unless it is very clear to you that none of the above may occur (nor or in the future) I would go with a parser.